# how to run docker container with external volume

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I want to run a container that I started with Docker Compose from the command line in the following figure.

Since the container started with docker compose gives a database error, I want to reach the same volume by starting another container.

I need to run some psql commands

docker-compose file

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  db:
    image: postgis/postgis:12-master
    env_file:
      - docker.env
    volumes:
      - bot_pdks_db_vol:/tmp/pgdata

volumes:
  bot_pdks_db_vol:
    external: true
```

.env file

```
POSTGRES_USER=postgres_user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_pass
DEFAULT_USER=postgres_user
DEFAULT_PASSWORD=postgres_pass
PGDATA=/tmp/pgdata
POSTGRES_DB=db
```

Comment: The easiest approach would probably to use the same docker-compose.yml which you used to create the first container. Did you try this already? You probably would not even need the `external` keyword. However, creating a second docker-compose.yml and including the volume with `external: true` should work as well.